# Unity: Unable to rearrange "Sorting Layer" for 2D game

Tags: unity, layers, sorting

Since yesterday I got a bit into game development with Unity (i've never done game development before), and I am currently making a small 2D game. I am attempting to rearrange the various layers in the "Sorting Layers" list. According to Unity's own official tutorial, you can simply drag & drop the layers around to rearrange them. However, when I click on one of the layers, I can not drag it anywhere.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements that can be dragged to new positions will have a = sign next to it in the inspector. The other ones below cannot be dragged but can be set up however you like.

Here is a pic the highlighted Layer in sorting layers is draggable

[image]

Note: you must select edit layers button located in the Layers Dropdown Tab shown at the top middle in the pic to get the Tags & Layers Inspector Window.