# Layers in Unity won't drag

Tags: unity, layers

I'm trying to rearrange my layers in Unity but I can't seem to drag them. When I try to do this I'm in edit layers under the heading sorting layers and I click on the = symbol and try to drag it but it won't move. I also tried restarting Unity twice but it won't resolve the problem.

Could someone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question that was asked recently](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172063/39518). Can you show us a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Dragging up and down anywhere on those layers except the text box field should move the layer. Possibly have a saved preset overriding the order? or a editor script that is forcing the sorting order? that would most likely cause them to stay in place and not move.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: when setting up the layers as shown in your screenshot, I can re-order them just fine. Can you replicate this problem in a new, empty project? If not, then as Justin says there may be something in your current project that's overriding your layer order. If it happens in a new project too, then it could be a problem with your Unity installation. You can try re-installing or reporting the issue to Unity's support team.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Unity are you using? I've tried this in 2019.1.2f1 & 3f1 and it works fine, but another question reports a similar problem in an "a" version - so it might be a bug specific to that version.

Comment: DMGregory it happend as well when I tried it in a new project. I tried it at my schoolcomputer too and on there the layers just drag normally. (Unity keeps crashing and takes a really long time to load on the schoolcomputers so that's why I can only work on it on the PC at home where the problem occurs) The version that i'm using is 2019.2.0b2

Comment: [Another user reports that running the 2019.1.3f1 version solved this problem for them](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172132/how-can-i-rearrange-layers-in-unity-2d#comment305659_172132). Is that an option you can try?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Thank you