# How can I rearrange layers in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity, layers

I'm new to using Unity (2019.30a2) and am currently learning by watching Brackey's (youtube) "[How to make a 2D Game in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on9nwbZngyw)"

At 6:58 he is able to rearrange his layers easily.  On my hand, I can create but am unable to change the order of the layers.

Looking at other questions on similar subjects hasn't provided me with a solution yet.  I'm currently working around it but feel this will hinder me in the future.

The screenshot of the unmovable layers is included below:

[image: Screenshot of unmovable layers]

Comment: I can't reproduce this in the latest stable version. Try 2019.1.3f1 and see if the problem persists - it could be a bug in the "a" release.

Comment: I did what you recommended and I am able to move the layers. thank you